# How to read from multiple RepositoryItemReaders and write into one RepositoryItemWriter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to read from around 7-8 different database tables, thereon combine all of those data into one which is then to be written into a single JSON file. Since Reader and Writer seems to be tightly coupled and serve one read and one write, I was wondering is there a way to read multiple datasources and combine those within the processor into one output using RepositoryItemReader and RepositoryItemWriter.

Comment: Are copying data verbatim from these 7 tables? Is having a single query that joins data from these tables an option for you?

Comment: The data is being pulled from multiple databases in order to generate a unified data structure to serve a service, there for multiple repository calls and manual mapping of those data into a new data structure format.

Comment: ok in that case I believe a staging table is a good option for you.

Comment: I thought about that, but the issue is we are talking about millions of records to be read, the IO cost would be extremely high.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use composition pattern by implementing a custom `ItemReader` which internally contains those 7-8 `RepositoryItemReaders` . In your custom `ItemReader` , you use these `RepositoryItemReaders` to collect all the data into a kind of container or tuple object and pass it to the `ItemProcessor` to process.

Code wise it looks like:

```java
public class MyItemReader implements ItemReader<Tuple> {

    private RepositoryItemReader r1;
    private RepositoryItemReader r2;
    private RepositoryItemReader r3;
    ......
    private RepositoryItemReader r6;
    private RepositoryItemReader r7;

    public Tuple read(){
        return new Tuple(r1.read(),r2.read() ....., r6.read() , r7.read());
    }

}

public class Tuple {
    private Table1 t1;
    private Table2 t2;
    private Table3 t3;
    .....
    private Table6 t6;
    private Table7 t7;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ken, I autowired multiple repositories in the reader and managed to pull the data and pass it on, but since I am calling these once again in the processor, I wondered if there would be a more efficient way of approaching this.